# JavaScript deep remove object property by using another object as selector

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I have object like this:

```
var myObj = {
    first: {
        sub: {
            prop1: "some text",
            prop2: "some more text"
        },
        sub2: {
            prop1: "Something",
            prop2: "Something2",
        }
    },
    second: {
        stuff: "More stuff...lots of stuff"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to remove property from this object by using another object as selector. For example:

```
var delSeletor = {
    first: {
        sub: {
            prop2: ""
        }
    }
}
```

So `delete( delSelector, myObject)` should return:

```
var myObj = {
    first: {
        sub: {
            prop1: "some text",
        },
        sub2: {
            prop1: "Something",
            prop2: "Something2",
        }
    },
    second: {
        stuff: "More stuff...lots of stuff"
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm not looking for solution using the ".dot" selector eg: `delete('first.sub.prop2', myObj)` like shown in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059951/deleting-js-object-properties-a-few-levels-deep).

Comment: remove means the same object? does the selector start always with a root key?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler if your `delSelector` was an array? ie `["first", "sub", "prop2" ]` kinda like how xpath works.

Comment: What if you could have a piece of code that transform your initial object into the `dot` notation and then use the `delete` given in the other thread? Would that answer you question?

Comment: yes, it means removing from the myObj and yes the selector always start with the root key ( in this case first ) and follows the exact path to that properly.

Comment: @Halcyon & @atomrc I'm using that solution in this moment, but I'm trying to find some more efficient and fast working solution, that will work on directly on object level, instead of converting the object selector into array or `dot` selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate the object `selector` for the keys to delete and check

- if key does not exist, return
- if property of the selector object is an object then call the delete function `deleteKeys` again with the key. Otherwise delete the key form the source object.

```js
function deleteKeys(object, selector) {
    Object.keys(selector).forEach(function (k) {
        if(!(k in object)) {
            return;
        }
        if (typeof selector[k] === 'object') {
            deleteKeys(object[k], selector[k]);
        } else {
            delete object[k];
        }
    });
}

var myObj = { first: { sub: { prop1: "some text", prop2: "some more text" }, sub2: { prop1: "Something", prop2: "Something2", } }, second: { stuff: "More stuff...lots of stuff" } },
    delSeletor = { first: { sub: { prop2: "" } } };

deleteKeys(myObj, delSeletor);

console.log(myObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Excellent solution and initial tests show much better performance.

Answer (score 1):

We now use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for data processing tasks like this. It's very powerful once you wrap your head around it. Here is how you'd solve your question.

Note:

- First we scan the first selector object and extract the paths. Then we use the paths to delete the corresponding targets.
- This would work for arrays as well with minor modifications

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const prune = (sel, input) => {
  const needles = objectScan(['**'], {
    joined: true,
    filterFn: ({ value }) => typeof value === 'string'
  })(sel);
  return objectScan(needles, {
    rtn: 'count',
    filterFn: ({ parent, property }) => {
      delete parent[property];
    }
  })(input);
};

const myObj = { first: { sub: { prop1: 'some text', prop2: 'some more text' }, sub2: { prop1: 'Something', prop2: 'Something2' } }, second: { stuff: 'More stuff...lots of stuff' } };

const delSeletor = { first: { sub: { prop2: '' } } };

console.log(prune(delSeletor, myObj)); // return deletion counts
// => 1
console.log(myObj);
// => { first: { sub: { prop1: 'some text' }, sub2: { prop1: 'Something', prop2: 'Something2' } }, second: { stuff: 'More stuff...lots of stuff' } }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that uses functional programming with `map` and `reduce`.

It recursively traverses both object and remove keys that are marked with an empty string on the object representing deletions

```
function deleteKeys(deletions, obj) {
    if (deletions === "") {
        return null
    }
    return Object
        .keys(obj)
        .map(key => {
            if (!(key in deletions)) {
                // if the key is not in the object containing 
                // the keys to delete
                return { [key]: obj[key] };
            }
            //recursively create a filtered object
            const filteredObj = deleteKeys(deletions[key], obj[key])

            // if that object is null, then return an empty object
            // else return the filtered object
            return filteredObj ? { [key]: filteredObj } : {}
        })

        // we now have an array of object that we need to merge together :)
        .reduce((acc, obj) => Object.assign({}, acc, obj), {})
}
```

Here are the tests I ran to code this:

```
const cleanedObj = deleteKeys(
    { first: "" },
    { first: "", second: { hi: ["heelo"] }}
);

console.log(cleanedObj);

const cleanedObj2 = deleteKeys(
    { second: { hi: "" }},
    { first: "", second: { hi: ["heelo"] }}
);

console.log(cleanedObj2);

const cleanedObj3 = deleteKeys(
    { second: "" },
    { first: "", second: { hi: ["heelo"] }}
);

console.log(cleanedObj3);
```

Thing worth noting about this solution, it is a **pure function** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) which means it wont modify your initial object but instead return a new one. No side effects FTW